# Problem of using args in VS Code custom tasks.json

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

So, Inside of the tasks array in the .vscode/tasks.json, I have this one task:

```
{
      "label": "buildReleaseIos",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "flutter build ios -t lib/main_prod.dart --dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_NAME=App Name --dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_SUFFIX=.myapp"
}
```

This task is valid and I'm able to execute it properly.

The problem is, if I move the `--dart-define` from command to the `args` array (which I think is the better practice), like this:

```
{
      "label": "buildReleaseIos",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "flutter build ios -t lib/main_prod.dart",
      "args": [
        "--dart-define=BCP_DART_DEFINE_APP_NAME=App Name",
        "--dart-define=BCP_DART_DEFINE_APP_SUFFIX=.myapp",
      ]
}
```

There's this error:

```
> Executing task: 'flutter build ios -t lib/main_prod.dart' '--dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_NAME=App Name' --dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_SUFFIX=.myapp <

/bin/bash: flutter build ios -t lib/main_prod.dart: No such file or directory
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', ''flutter build ios -t lib/main_prod.dart' '--dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_NAME=App Name' --dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_SUFFIX=.myapp'" terminated with exit code: 127.
```

But, I also have similar args usage in the `launch.json` which works fine:

```
{
      "name": "Flutter Debug Prod",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "program": "lib/main_prod.dart",
      "args": [
        "--dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_NAME=App Name",
      ],
}
```

Maybe I'm mistaken on how `args` in `tasks.json` works? Can you show me how to properly use args?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That translation in bash should look like

```
"/bin/bash '-c', 'flutter' 'build' 'ios' '-t' 'lib/main_prod.dart' '--dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_NAME=App Name' '--dart-define=DART_DEFINE_APP_SUFFIX=.myapp'
```

which means you need `flutter` in `program` and everything else as separate elements of `args`, or you can just put everything in `program`, but then whitespace quoting can be a bit wonky.

Comment: Yeah, at the end I put everything in the `command` property. It's kinda weird though, having 2 different kind of behavior between launch and tasks. Idk why is that.

Comment: if args present, program = "program to run" and args are separate args to that command.  If args absent, program = line to hand to shell, which may include args separated with the myriad of rules of a shell :)